# Definir CSS de acordo com navegador

Tags: css

Encontrei um comando para alterar CSS no Firefox:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    body {
        background: #f00;
    }
}
```

Esse comando vai colocar um fundo vermelho somente no firefox, por exemplo.

Achei muito útil, mas gostaria de saber se tem como eu fazer isso com outros browsers, mas nesse estilo, sem o uso dos `"<!--[if IE 8]>"` por exemplo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim é possível, está "técnica" tem um nome: **CSS Hack**, basicamente ela abusa dos erros de renderização dos navegadores, pois são propriedades escritas de uma forma errada justamente pra não funcionar mas os navegadores interpretam como instrução válida, por exemplo:

```
#teste {
    background-color: Red;
    _background-color: Black; // No IE o fundo ficará com a cor preta
}
```

Existem diversos **CSS Hacks**, quando você precisar de algum específico eu recomendo o site [Browserhacks](http://browserhacks.com/) para consulta.

O trecho que você postou `<!--[if IE 8]>`, é um comentário condicional: *"Os comentários condicionais são comentários incluídos no código HTML escritos exclusivamente para fazer uma parte do código funcionar no Internet Explorer."*, [fonte](http://tableless.com.br/comentarios-condicionais-nao-use/).

Answer (score 1):

Simples:

- `-moz` é para o Firefox
- `-ms` para o Internet Explorer
- `-o` para o Opera <= 12 (antes de adotar o WebKit como motor)
- `-webkit` para navegadores que usam o motor WebKit como o Chrome, Safari e muitos navegadores mobile como do próprio Android

Veja:

[(1)](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm)
[(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083056/css-what-are-moz-and-webkit)

### Atualização

Como disse o @NULL, isto funciona apenas para propriedades CSS3. Dependendo do caso pode ser suficiente.

Uma alternativa mais POG seria identificar o browser por Javascript e então carregar o CSS dinamicamente ([veja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996866/load-css-style-sheet-based-on-ie-document-mode)).

Comment: Amigo, o que você postou são prefixos para utilizar as novas propriedades do CSS3 em navegadores diferentes. [Fonte](http://tableless.com.br/prefixos-dos-browsers-a-web-precisa-de-voce/).

Comment: Não é isso que ele quer (propriedades diferentes para navegadores distintos)?

Comment: Mas o seu exemplo só funciona para as novas propriedades CSS3, tente utilizar por exemplo: `-moz-background-color: red;`, não mudou a cor do fundo somente no firefox né? (Na verdade não mudou a cor em nenhum). Seu comentário é válido somente para propriedades novas.

Comment: OK. Valeu pela correção. Editarei a resposta para deixar isto claro. =)

Answer (score 0):

Segundo o W3C

> A regra `'@document'` uma regra do grupo cuja condição depende da [URL do documento que está sendo formatado](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-conditional-20120911/#url-of-doc). Isso permite que as folhas de estilo, especialmente as folhas de estilo do usuário, para ter estilos que se aplicam somente a um conjunto de páginas, em vez de todas as páginas que usam a folha de estilo.

Desta forma você pode utilizar os prefixos para aplicar estilo especificamente a um browser e a alguma [url](/questions/tagged/url).
Para definir as regra de [url](/questions/tagged/url) você pode usar as seguintes propriedades:

- ***url***
- ***url-prefix(<string>)***
- ***domain(<string>)***
- ***regexp(<string>)***

Veja em [***Document queries: the ‘@document’ rule***](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-conditional-20120911/#at-document) como utilizar cada umas destas propriedades.

Comment: Lembrando que essa também é uma propriedade nova do CSS3 que ainda não foi completamente implementada, não funciona para navegadores antigos. [This is an experimental technology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document#Browser_compatibility)